# Update table using check null value from data reader

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, sqldatareader

My two columne  email and status on  tableemail i had use a data reader for count mail address and send  mail:

```
>  OleDbCommand cmd = null;
>             OleDbCommand cmd2 = null;
>             
>             string queryString = "select email,status from tableemail";
>             using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle.1; Data Source = xe;
> Password=eppspps;User ID = xpress; unicode=true"))
>             {
>                 OleDbCommand command= new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
>                 connection.Open();
>                 cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString);
>                 cmd.Connection = connection;
>                 OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>                
>                 while (reader.Read())
>                     
>                 {
>                     MailAddress to = new MailAddress(reader[0].ToString());
>                     message.To.Add(to);     
>                 }
```

this code is  work good, but
i need update  status  data to tablemail after check null value on data reader

```
> if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
>                 {
>                     cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(" UPDATE tableemail set status=1 where status is null", connection);
>                     cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
>                 }
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Unrelated tip: the command and reader are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block.

Comment: You haven't explained the problem, but I suspect that you need to have completed the first command before you do others. Just keep a list of the things you want to update and do it after the command finishes.

Comment: i can update using cmd check with reader values?

Comment: On re-reading, your update does not use the value from the reader, so it's easier: you don't need to keep track of anything. Just put in the `using` blocks that I mentioned, and put `cmd2` after the `using` block for `cmd`. Failing that, please [edit] the question to clarify what the problem is.

Comment: i had try while loop , how can put block suggest me pls

Comment: You already have a `using` block for the connection - what do you need me to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try to only use `cmd` to do `select` and `update`, and remove if `If(!reader.IsDBNull(1))` and move `update` code to outer loop.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = null;

string queryString = "select email,status from tableemail";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle.1; Data Source = xe;
 Password=eppspps;User ID = xpress; unicode=true"))
{
 OleDbCommand command= new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
 connection.Open();
 cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString);
 cmd.Connection = connection;
 OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read()) 
 {
     MailAddress to = new MailAddress(reader[0].ToString());
     message.To.Add(to);     
 }
  cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE tableemail set status=1 where status is null";
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

**EDIT**

if you want to use `update` in the while-loop you can try to use another `OleDbCommand` and execute update in `if`

```
string queryString = "select email,status from tableemail";
string updateString = "UPDATE tableemail set status=1 where email = @email";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle.1; Data Source = xe;
 Password=eppspps;User ID = xpress; unicode=true"))
{
 connection.Open();
 OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString,Connection);
 OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(updateString,Connection);
 OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read()) 
 {
     MailAddress to = new MailAddress(reader[0].ToString());
     message.To.Add(to);     
     if(!reader.IsDBNull(1)){
         cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
         cmd2.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("email", reader["email"]));
         cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: it possible check with data reader values  during update processs??

Comment: Yes but is there any column is `PK` you might update data by PK.

Comment: if i set pk  in email column as PK how can i update it?

Comment: You just need to use a column for `update` and make sure this data won't duplicate. If your e-mail isn't duplicate in your table you can use it.

Comment: actually update required for send auto mail  when insert new  information under the email address,  i want to be update status which mail all ready sent  i am sending mail using data reader and i want to be update data reader values

Comment: I think my first answer could help you make your expect